# h1 tag double renders when I push to production on vercel, I if run locally it renders fine

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

This is my next.js code: https://github.com/albbus-stack/personal-site.

This issue resides in the https://github.com/albbus-stack/personal-site/blob/main/pages/index.js page when i push to production my site on vercel; when i run it locally all is fine and the h1 with my name renders only one time. The even more strange thing is that if i refresh the deployed page after the first render it renders correctly.

You can see yourself on the production deploy at https://site-one-eta.vercel.app/.

pictures attached: [bad first render on production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qikJM.png),
[same production page after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmXr8.png)

Comment: I don't know, sometimes it works sometimes not. It heavily depends on the client I'm loading the site from.

Comment: Sorry I've updated the github page, now you can read it more clearly